# Knockout JS 3.0.0: Display Map object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have to display map object in my task. I tried in JSfiddle it worked. When I implement the same in my project it didn't then I found that JSfiddle online used *Knockout JS 3.4.0* lib whereas my project is using *knockoutJS 3.2.0*.

Is there anyway to make this code adaptable for *KnockoutJS 3.2.0* ?

Are there no way other than updating the library ?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li data-bind="foreach: model">
    <span data-bind="text: Main"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Sub">
      <li><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

KnockoutJS 3.0.0:

```
var viewModel = function() {

  model = ko.observableArray([{
    Main: "Main1",
    Sub: ["hello", "hi"]
  }, {
    Main: "Main2",
    Sub: ["one", "two"]
  }]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Here is my fiddle: [Display Map object](https://jsfiddle.net/p5oL3wf5/)
Same fiddle works when I chnage the lib plugin to Knockout JS 3.4.0.
Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: Works for me with `KO 3.0.0` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5oL3wf5/3/)

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the protocol error where in your knockout 3.0.0 source script is loaded using `http` and not `https`.

Here is what the `console` says when you try to run it under knockout 3.0.0 -

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/p5oL3wf5/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.0.0.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Which is rightly followed by -

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined(…)
```

Whereas for others it is working because they have [this link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js) loaded as an external resource in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5oL3wf5/3/), which if you observe starts with `https` and not `http`.

As far as the differences between the two versions of knockout scripts go, for what your fiddle is using, they are pretty much the same.